# A square matrix with some specific properties is always non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix with the following properties:

$a_{ii}=1$ $\ \forall i$, if $a_{ij}\neq 0$ then $a_{ji}= 0$ $\ \forall i,j$ and $i\neq j$;

Is it possible to prove that $A$ is non-singular?

and what if $a_{ij}\geq0$ $\forall i,j$?

Comment: I would write "matrix". One matrix, two matrices.

Comment: corrected! thanks

Answer (score 3):

No.  For example, the matrix
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&-1\\
-1&1&0\\
0&-1&1
}
$$
is singular.

---

For an all positive example, note that
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1
}
$$
is singular.

Comment: thank you! and what if $a_{ij}\geq0$ ?

Comment: @Anton I'd have to think about it.  You might be interested in knowing that a matrix is necessarily invertible if it is [strictly diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).

Comment: @Anton see my latest edit.

Comment: perfect! thanks